# Adding space between uppercase character java

Tags: java, string

I am a beginner in Java. Below is a piece of code that I wrote. the purpose is to add a space between each upper case character for example for string="ILoveMyDog" to
"I Love My Dog". However the outcome of this code is "ILoveMy Dog". Can someone help me figured out what is wrong? upperCaseList is another method to extract the index of all uppercase character and put them into a list, and I am pretty sure that part is correct

```
for (int i = 0; i < upperCaseList.size(); i++) {
    newStr = w.replace(w.substring(upperCaseList.get(i), upperCaseList.get(i)+1), " "+ w.substring(upperCaseList.get(i), upperCaseList.get(i)+1));
    }
return newStr
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of `upperCaseList`? Is it `0,1,5,7`?

Comment: `I am pretty sure that part is correct` - famous last words. Until a problem is solved you don't know where the problem is. Post a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are overwriting the result of `String.replace` by reassigning `newStr` inside the loop. So, you only see the effect of the last replacement.

Assuming the content of `upperCaseList` is `1, 5, 7`.

After Loop iteration 1, `newStr` has `I LoveMyDog`

After Loop iteration 2, `newStr` has `ILove MyDog` (you are not using the previous result, rather using the original string)

After Loop iteration 3, `newStr` has `ILoveMy Dog`

Try this,

```
String newStr = w;
for (int i = 0; i < upperCaseList.size(); i++) {
    newStr = newStr.replace(w.substring(upperCaseList.get(i), upperCaseList.get(i)+1), " "+ w.substring(upperCaseList.get(i), upperCaseList.get(i)+1));
}
```

There are plenty of ways to solve this though. Rather than storing the list of indices containing the uppercase characters and using `String.substring` and `String.replace`, you can use `StringBuilder` to build up the string from the original string by looping through the characters and checking if it is upper/lower cased.

```
StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1; i < w.length(); i++) { //Note: Starting at index 1
    if (Character.isUpperCase(w.charAt(i))) {
        resultBuilder.append(" ")
                .append(w.charAt(i));
    } else {
        resultBuilder.append(w.charAt(i));
    }
}
System.out.println(resultBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: That make so much sense. Thank You so much

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are creating the upperCaseList, I suggest to have one loop for all. Hope below code will work for your requirement.

```
public void test(){

    String str ="ILoveMyDog";
    StringBuilder strBuilder  = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i< str.length() ; i++) {
        if(Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))){
            //add space
            strBuilder.append(" ");
        }
        //add the orginal char
        strBuilder.append(str.charAt(i));
    }
    //use toString method 
    System.out.println(strBuilder.toString());
}
```